First Time Home Owner in Fulshear TX, Foundation watering advice
I just moved to my first house in Fulshear Texas from Ohio. I'm not used to the foundation watering stuff here. I found some gravel bed at the left/right/back side of the house, this was done by the previous owner. I'm guessing it's for irrigation. With the Texas heat in this Summer, I'm not sure how to water the foundation. I tried connecting some soaker hoses but I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing given that I have gravel close to the foundation. Please I need some recommendations. Thanks.
See link for how the foundation looks like. Thanks. 
[![Foundation with gravel]


Not familiar with "foundation watering "  Here (Fla.)  What does it entail and why?

Does your town have recommendations? Denton, TX has a useful handout: https://www.cityofdenton.com/DocumentCenter/View/169/Avoid-Foundation-Problems-PDF

@MTA, Well I learned something new today.  I never heard of watering your foundation. Here in Fla. the greater issue is getting water away from the foundation.  Our climate makes for never needing this.  That is why I never heard of "foundation watering"  I am now informed. Thank You.

@MTA thanks for sharing that. I will try to see if I can find one here in Fulshear.

@RMDman this is my first time of worry about issues like this. Where I lived in Ohio, I never worried about this. Coming to Texas is a whole new chapter for me

This question screams out for answers from people in Texas.  Looking at the Denton information, it sounds like the problem is having black gumbo clay next to the foundation.  I wonder if the gravel is to keep the clay away from the foundation and allow for drainage and expansion/contraction.  I.e. perhaps the gravel means that you don't have to do this.  It may be worth having a foundation or home inspection company come out and tell you if you need to do this.  Is your foundation a slab?  Or pier-and-beam?  A professional could tell you.

It's a slab foundation.

Wha? Foundation watering? Who knew?
In areas of Texas where the soil is so-called black gumbo clay, it is recommended to water the area near the foundation daily with a soaker hose to maintain a steady moisture content. Failing to do so leads to foundation damage along with wall cracks, sticking windows and doors, and other problems.
Soil that is sandy or sandy loam doesn't need watering.
Black gumbo clay soil is highly expansive when wet and it shrinks when dry. The goal is to maintain a steady moisture content to reduce expansion and contraction of the soil.
The City of Denton, TX publishes a handout that you can see here by clicking the images to zoom:

And:

YouTube has a number of videos about Texas foundation watering.

And for the science nerds (pdf): https://www.soils4teachers.org/files/s4t/k12outreach/tx-state-soil-booklet.pdf
